# re-installing dotnet on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm new to Linux. I had VSCode and .Net Core running on Ubuntu 16.04. I manually removed the entire folder at ./usr/share/dotnet

I followed the instructions at http://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu to re-install .Net core. However, the 'dotnet' program is not being installed. Typing 'dotnet --version' in the terminal says dotnet is not found.

How can I re-install .Net Core completely?

Thanks in advance.